# Pick Image From A Subfolder In Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have extracted frames of a video and saved in a subfolder of the folder where the matlab code is saved. The frames saved have an extension of `.jpg' .

The path of my matlab code is :

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\deepsir\arnold\new\arnold.m
```

The path of an image is :

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\deepsir\arnold\new\Movie Frames from rhinos\Frame 1.jpg
```

I want to read and display these images from the subfolder. Can someone help me out as how to pick the image from that `subfolder` and then subsequently display it using `imshow` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imshow('C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\deepsir\arnold\new\Movie Frames from rhinos\Frame 1.jpg')`?

If that doesn't work: `imshow('C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\deepsir\arnold\new\"Movie Frames from rhinos"\
Frame 1.jpg"')`

Recommendation: change your foldername to remove the spaces. Movie_Frames_from_rhinos

Comment: can u also tell me how to write that chosen image back into that subfolder after modifying it ?

Comment: @completesingh `imwrite(yourImage,'C:\Users\Amogh\Downloads\deepsir\arnold\new\Movie Frames from rhinos\Frame 1.jpg');`

Comment: I gave you those for free because you're fairly new here, but for future reference: please Google your question before asking it. The first result for the query "MATLAB save image" answered your question.